# Handler Memory Leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a Handler which is declared on the main thread:

```
  mainHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {

                    case 1:

                        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                        mTextView.setText(bundle.getString("message"));
                        break;

                    . . .

                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Where mTextView is a TextView defined onCreate().

I have a task which is used in a separate thread. The runnable stores `mainHandler` from the main thread and tells it to send messages:

```
public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Handler mHandler;

    public SomeRunnable(Handler handler) throws IOException {
        . . .    
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                    . . .

                    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                    . . .
                    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.hashCode() + ": " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

I have seen that you can potentially create memory leaks by using methods such as `Handler#postDelayed()` if the Handler class is not static. But, I am using `Handler#sendMessage()` which instantly puts a Message in the message queue.

Am I still in danger of having a memory leak? Even with:

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mThread.interrupt();
        mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear from the code you posted, but does your `Handler` or `Runnable` hold any references to non-transient objects? Further, contrary to what you seem to say, I'd expect a `static`ly held `Handler` to be more prone to memory leaks than what I see above.

Comment: @323go my Runnable "SomeRunnable" holds the same address as my Handler "mainHandler" from the main thread. Is this what you are defining as non-transient? My Handler does not hold any references, although it does refer to the TextView within the main thread.

Comment: You could make the reference to `mainHandler` a `WeakReference` then, just to be safe. Otherwise it looks like you'd be ok.

Comment: Zack, another way would be if you use `Eclipse Memory Analyzer` if you are using `eclipse`. And see if your `Application` leaks Memory and with that tool you can also determine what is causing the leak in your program. See [here](https://eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: @Mike I just downloaded this as of this morning. Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely try this out and analyze the memory. Just thought I would ask if conceptually there could be a potential memory leak with my implementation.

Comment: @cosair992 Thank you so much as this was my initial assumption. So just to clarify: since I have removed messages/callbacks onDestroy() there shouldn't be a concern with a memory leak. I seem to not understand what a weak reference holds. what is the difference between weak vs. just a regular reference? And could you elaborate a little more on why a weak reference would not make a difference? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you were holding a reference to the `Handler` in a different thread too. In that case, holding a weak reference in the thread is definitely appropriate, as the thread would leak the `Handler` for the duration of it's lifetime otherwise. You might want to look into using an `AyncTaskLoader`, as it is designed to handle this automatically, although it's difficult to implement.

Comment: @corsair992 Yeah I thought that might make sense. But even if I call Thread.interrupt() onDestroy?

Comment: @Zack: That depends on how responsive to interrupts your thread is. If the thread is performing I/O then that would be interrupted. You should probably hold a weak reference anyway, as there is no guarantee on how long a different thread will take to execute/terminate.

Comment: @corsair992 And I also have blocking operations using Socket programming on the separate thread so maybe it is a good thing to have a Weak Reference to the Handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address all eventualities, you could make `mHandler` a `WeakReference` as below:

```
public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private WeakReference<Handler> mHandlerRef;

    public SomeRunnable(Handler handler) throws IOException {
        . . .    
        mHandlerRef = new WeakReference<Handler>( handler );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                    . . .
                    Handler mHandler = mHandlerRef.get();
                    if( mHandler != null ) {
                        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                        . . .
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.hashCode() + ": " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm going to see how this has an effect on my application and I'll let you know my final solution.

Comment: should the mHandlerRef.get(); be called each time within the while loop or can this be executed outside of the loop?

Comment: Depends on how much work you do in the loop, or whether you yield to other threads in there. The `run` will execute pretty soon after it's posted; the only situation where using the `WeakReference` helps is if you have a long running `Runnable` which you want to be able to interrupt/abort cleanly.

Comment: The Runnable is executed within a separate thread and lasts until the Application has been terminated.

Comment: Then you'd definitely want to call the `get()` just before using it, as referenced `Handler` might already be gone. If it returns `null` this would also be a signal to stop execution of the thread.